# How to calculate effect size when I have the mean difference, CI of that mean difference and n?

Tags: effect-size

Any advice without using any coding software would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 95% confidence interval using the normal distribution, where $CI_u$ is the upper confidence interval, and $\Delta$ is the difference, then:

$SE=\frac{CI_{u} - \Delta}{1.96}$

We could then calculate the $t-$statistic as:

$t = \frac{\Delta}{SE}$

Then, following [this definition of Cohen's D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d) we could calculate:

$D = \frac{t}{\sqrt{N}}$

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance!